# Create a new column with values from parsed xml data

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, parsing

I am using SQL Server 2008 and am relatively new to SQL.

I have a table that contains a column with datatype `xml`. The XML in this column contains restaurant information for customer receipts:

```
<order>
    <Check>
        <CheckHeader>
            <CheckNumber>279084</CheckNumber>
            <ServerNumber>186</ServerNumber>
            <ServerName>ServerName</ServerName>
            <CheckTotal>8.95</CheckTotal>
        </CheckHeader>
    </Check>
```

After doing some research on here I learned how to parse out the information I care about, i.e. the `<CheckTotal>`:

```
SELECT 
    order_xml.value('(/order//CheckTotal/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as CheckTotal 
FROM
    CheckTable
```

Where I am no struggling is how do I add in this parsed `CheckTotal` value into a new column within this `CheckTable` table (of course ensuring that the `CheckTotal` matches up with the appropriate row).

My `CheckTable` table looks like this:

[image: CheckTable Image]

What have I already done?

Well I altered my table to add in a new column and I attempted to create a `@temptTb` where I added in the parsed `CheckTable` value AND the parsed `CheckNumber` value. I parsed the `CheckNumber` value as well in an attempt to ensure that when I would join these two tables in an attempt to update the new column I would match up the correct `CheckTotal` based on the `CheckNumber`... of course it turns out that for my dataset `CheckNumber`'s are recycled and thus reused.

So now, and I sure do hope such a solution exists, I can immediately add my parsed xml `CheckTotal` value directly into a new column in my `CheckTable` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML only ever contains *one* order with *one* `<Check>` inside - you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.CheckTable
SET CheckTotal = CheckXml.value('(/order[1]/Check[1]/CheckHeader[1]/CheckTotal[1])', 'decimal(18,2)')
```

It gets a bit trickier if your XML contains multiple elements at any level of the element hierarchy....

Comment: That worked out really well! Just out of curiosity - within the CheckXml.Value function, what does 'decimal(18,2)' do?

Comment: @BrianP: it converts the value contained in that `<CheckTotal>` XML element to that particular datatype - so what the call to `.value()` returns is really a `decimal(18,2)` value - exactly as intended